# C++ character array allocation error

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

I have a function designed to get a file's contents:

```
bool getFileContents(std::string loc, std::string &code) {
    std::ifstream file(loc.c_str());

    if(!file.is_open())
        return err("Source file could not be read");

    int length;
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    length = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    char *buffer = new char[length];
    file.read(buffer, length);
    code = buffer;
    delete[] buffer;

    file.close();

    return true;
}
```

When I run this function, the file's length is always retrieved accurately. However, if I call the function once with a file, call it again with a nonexistent file, then call it one more time with the original file, the character string 'buffer' is larger than the int 'length'.

Well, that may not be accurate, rather - when the string 'buffer' is copied to the string 'code', 'code' is longer than 'length'. 'code' is, in each instance, instantiated immediately before the call to 'getFileContents', so it's not a matter of a previous value.

This also seems to occur if I retrieve the contents of a file, subsequently add or remove some text from the file, and retrieve the same file's contents again.

I have little experience with character strings, and figure that I'm not using them correctly, but the code I'm using came from an example, and I can't for the life of me find anything wrong with it.

Thanks for any help,
Wyatt

Comment: Are you not familiar with exceptions? It looks like you're handling errors by calling a function to report the error, which always returns false, so that you can use the return value to propagate the exception, while forcing the caller to create an out-parameter. This is incredibly backwards. Return values with `return`. Use exceptions to report exceptional events (like the file not existing when it's supposed to).

Comment: What benefit would exceptions provide? I'm not building this code for anyone else, and having a global error string is hardly an impediment to my work. I rather prefer this method, it centralises error handling, and is a lot more terse than a try/catch block.

Comment: Couldn't you just use the 'code' variable and copy the contents to it from the file reading (after all, you're passing the parameter by reference)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the problem is that `code = buffer` relies on a NUL (\0) character to know where the buffer ends. You may be getting the NUL character by chance sometimes (esp. when the program has just started), but not always. Hence the intermittent behaviour.

Try replacing `code = buffer` with `code = std::string(buffer, length)`.

Comment: To avoid unneeded allocation, it's better to use `code.assign(buffer, buffer+length)`

Comment: **Doc Brown**, what if a file contains \0's inside?

Answer (score 0):

Apart of the \0 problem described by **aix**, you do double allocation, which is not necessary here and unsafe (it might be an exception before `delete`, and you'll have a memory leak). Instead, you can allocate the buffer inside the string, as follows:

```
code.resize(length);
file.read(&code[0], length);
```

And don't forget to check the return value of `read`. It is not guaranteed that all `length` bytes will be read in one step.